# Spring boot war with external tomcat setting context path

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, tomcat9

Iam working on a spring boot application, we are using war packaging. When i run the application in my local machine with bootRun or in STS,it is working as expected, but when i deploy it in PCF, the context path is not applying. After some research i came to know that server.servlet.context-path will not work in external tomcat, so i added context.xml with
 in webapp/META-INF, but it is still not working. The API /test is working but it is supposed to be /myPath/test. I spent lot of time on research haven't found a working solution. Can anyone help. Thanks.

Comment: The default when deploying to Tomcat, is that the `.war` file name becomes the Context Path, so if you rename the file to `myPath.war` before deploying, your `/myPath/test` URL should work. Read the [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#A_word_on_Contexts) for more information on Contexts.

Comment: Thank you for response, we are deploying our war on PCF, even our war file name is also not considered as context path. Any idea about this?